# как отобразить на экране QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь вывести на экран имя `User`. [image: Вот как это выглядит]

Вот мой `views.py`:

```py
bid = Bid.objects.filter(listing_offer_id=itemID).order_by("bid_offer").values()
last_bid = bid.last()# the last value of sorted list of bids

bid_offer = last_bid["bid_offer"] # gets the max value of bid offers   
bid_owner = User.objects.filter(id = last_bid['bid_owner_id'])# gets the owner of the bid
```

Вот модель `Bid`:

```py
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid_offer = models.IntegerField()
    listing_offer = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "listings", null = True)
    bid_owner= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

вот модель `Listing`:

```py
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'auctions/media/images')
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null = True, related_name = "category", default = "None")
    price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

модель `User` это `AbstractUser`

Как вывести просто `ismail` без скобок и т.д?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы вывести имя пользователя `bid_owner` без скобок и т.д., вы можете использовать атрибут `username` объекта User.

```
bid_owner = User.objects.filter(id=last_bid['bid_owner_id'])
print(bid_owner.username)
```

Но лучше вместо атрибута `id` использовать `pk`, т.к. `id` - это функция Python, а `pk` - это Джанговская функция.

Comment: там ошибка:
**'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'username'**

Comment: а как у вас называется поле где имя User в модели, то и используете вместо username